# How to trim stamp string value

Tags: javascript, regex, string, lodash

I have a requirement in my codebase where I need to trim the timestamp if it has a timezone on it.

An example of a timestamp I may receive:

> "2017/08/23 12:00:00 Z"or "2017/08/23 12:00:00 +05:30"

My desired output should be:

> "2017/08/23 12:00:00"or "2017/08/23 12:00:00"

Comment: It was mostly okay, it just needed a bit of formatting and fixing some grammar. Anyway, good luck :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could do something like this:

```js
var d1 = "2017/08/23 12:00:00 Z"
var d2 = "2017/08/23 12:00:00 +05:30"
var d3 = "2017/08/23 12:00:00"

const getDatePart = d => d.split(' ').reduce((r,c,i) => i <= 1 ? `${r} ${c}` : r)

console.log(getDatePart(d1))
console.log(getDatePart(d2))
console.log(getDatePart(d3))
```

It would do the job via `String.split` & `reduce`. It would cover the date strings with one `' '` between the date & time.

Answer (score 0):

Use `lastIndexOf` method to find the last space and then substring to it.

```js
var date = "2017/08/23 12:00:00 Z";
var date1 = "2017/08/23 12:00:00 +05:30";


console.log(date.substring(0, date.lastIndexOf(" ")));
console.log(date1.substring(0, date.lastIndexOf(" ")));
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you process one datetime at a time, you can use this regex:

```
/(?<=\").*?(?:(?=Z)|(?=[+-]))/
```

It looks back to find a double `quote`, then matches any char zero or more times (non greedy), then it looks forward for either a `'Z'` or plus `[+]` or minus `[-]`.